# Permission denied when creating an S3 bucket with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am having permission issues when deploying resources to AWS with Terraform.

I have a terraform template which deploys an S3 bucket. I get `ACCESS DENIED 403` when creating the bucket.

I used my personal keys (admin rights), but now I have also tried using the root keys, and same result.

Terraform version is 0.14.

Any help is appreciated // Timme

This is the terraform snippet that creates the S3 bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "root_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = templatefile("templates/s3-policy.json", { bucket = var.bucket_name })

  website {
    redirect_all_requests_to = "https://www.${var.domain_name}"
  }

  tags = var.common_tags
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete error message?

Comment: ```Error: Error creating S3 bucket: AccessDenied: Access Denied
 status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx``` @jordanm

Comment: It is an Ubuntu container

Comment: I have know tried upgrading to 1.2.6 and get same error

Comment: How are you providing aws credentials to the container?

Comment: @jordanm
I am actually doing it as env variables, inside terraform and in ```.aws/credentials``` 

I also just found this: 

```status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx=: timestamp=2022-08-12T16:18:50.169Z
2022/08/12 16:18:50 [DEBUG] aws_s3_bucket.root_bucket: apply errored, but we're indicating that via the Error pointer rather than returning it: Error creating S3 bucket: AccessDenied: Access Denied
 status code: 403, request id: xxx, host id: xxx =```